# Autoware.ai runtime_manager "Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager"

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed latest version of autoware.ai (ver 1.12.0) and ran the ROSBAG demo described here.

https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/ROSBAG-Demo

From rviz, I can confirm that demo is working fine. However, in the terminal window that opened by runtime_manager is giving "Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager".

What does this message means and is this something I should try to fix or just ignore?

The following is the entire messages on the terminal screen after I launched "Map", "Sensing", "Localization" and "Detection" launch files.

My environment:
x86
ROS Kinetics
Ubuntu 16.04LTS
Autoware.ai Ver 1.12.0

```
bash: ./../../../setup.bash: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/hiro/.rviz’: File exists
/home/hiro/autoware.ai/install/runtime_manager/lib/runtime_manager/runtime_manager_dialog.py:2865: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item. 
  wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
loading param.yaml
loading qs.yaml
Subscribe[localization] topic=/ndt_stat, key=/ndt_stat.NDTStat.exe_time
Subscribe[detection] topic=/topic2, key=/topic2
Subscribe[detection] topic=/topic1, key=/topic1
loading setup.yaml
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_x', '1.2']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_y', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_z', '2.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_yaw', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_pitch', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_roll', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'localizer', 'velodyne']
loading map.yaml
loading sensing.yaml
loading computing.yaml
loading interface.yaml
loading data.yaml
loading simulation.yaml
['rosparam', 'set', '/use_sim_time', 'false']
loading status.yaml
loading state.yaml
loading topics.yaml
['rosparam', 'set', '/use_sim_time', 'true']
['rosbag', 'play', '--start=140', '--clock', '/home/hiro/.autoware/sample_moriyama_150324.bag']
pid=22965
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager
['roslaunch', '/home/hiro/autoware.ai/src/autoware/documentation/autoware_quickstart_examples/launch/rosbag_demo/my_map.launch']
pid=22992
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00167_-00864.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00153_-00852.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00159_-00859.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00160_-00861.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00148_-00849.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00168_-00866.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00147_-00851.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00149_-00847.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00156_-00854.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00158_-00858.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00147_-00847.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00154_-00852.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00158_-00857.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00154_-00851.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00167_-00866.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00168_-00865.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00169_-00868.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00147_-00849.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00153_-00850.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00154_-00853.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00161_-00861.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00168_-00867.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00151_-00849.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00153_-00851.pcd
['roslaunch', '/home/hiro/autoware.ai/src/autoware/documentation/autoware_quickstart_examples/launch/rosbag_demo/my_sensing.launch']
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00152_-00850.pcd
pid=23183
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00150_-00848.pcd
 Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00156_-00856.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00167_-00865.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00157_-00856.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00148_-00848.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00152_-00851.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00156_-00855.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00168_-00868.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00161_-00860.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00159_-00857.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00150_-00847.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00164_-00863.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00157_-00857.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00162_-00861.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00151_-00850.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00165_-00864.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00149_-00848.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00155_-00852.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00160_-00859.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00163_-00861.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00160_-00858.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00158_-00856.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00155_-00854.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00160_-00860.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00159_-00858.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00147_-00850.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00148_-00847.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00163_-00862.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00151_-00848.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00155_-00853.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00152_-00849.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00149_-00846.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00166_-00865.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00147_-00846.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00167_-00867.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00165_-00863.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00166_-00864.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00155_-00855.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00162_-00862.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00150_-00846.pcd
load /home/hiro/.autoware/data/map/pointcloud_map/bin_Laser-00164_-00862.pcd
['roslaunch', '/home/hiro/autoware.ai/src/autoware/documentation/autoware_quickstart_examples/launch/rosbag_demo/my_localization.launch']
pid=23360
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager
['roslaunch', '/home/hiro/autoware.ai/src/autoware/documentation/autoware_quickstart_examples/launch/rosbag_demo/my_detection.launch']
pid=23455
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
Failed connect to /tmp/autoware_proc_manager
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329001/autoware.ai-runtime_manager-%22failed-connect-to-/tmp/autoware_proc_manager%22/) by [hirokawakubo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44104/hirokawakubo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-07-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is OK, especially for the demo. The `run_proc_manager` script is called by the `run` script, which is called by the launch file that you run in the demo. `run_proc_manager` creates a file at /tmp/autoware_proc_manager which keeps track of the processes that are launched by the Runtime Manager GUI. After this, the terminal from which you launched the runtime manager tries to connect to the file to output data on the terminal about which processes are being launched. The data are just informational so not connecting to that file is fine.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2019-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hirokawakubo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44104/hirokawakubo/) on 2020-01-14**:
Hi Josh,

Thanks for the response. It's good to know that it's not a real issue.